# Increase elevation for a portion of the raster covered by a shapefile

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, dem, raster-calculator

I have a raster of California. I have the shapefile over CA. I would like to keep the bits hanging off into OR, NV, and AZ. What I'd like to do is to raise CA up about 200 feet from where it is, making it "pop out" from the surrounding states. There has got to be a way to use the Serval toolbar to select the raster portion covered by the shapefile and then use the raster calculator to add x-feet to that selection.

Comment: you can add a column to your shapefile, set the value to 200 for california, then rasterize it using the new column as rastervalue and use the rastercalculator to add it to your raster of CA.

Comment: Alright, I’m liking how that sounds. Can you walk me through that? What would the calculation be in the calculator?

Comment: I think questions like this are often better if there's a "why" rather than people answering with a blind "how". If it's for cartographic purposes only, there are certainly easier and more effective techniques than actually manipulating a raster with fake data. That is, it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I carve wood maps so I’d like to have the state I am carving “stand out” from the neighbors.

Comment: In which case I think you do in fact have a good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `Menu Raster / Converstion / Rasterize`, select the polygon and the value you want to add, `200` in your case. Select Pixel size (`Width/Horizontal resolution` and `Height/Vertical resolution`) from the raster layer. Be sure that `Assign a specified nodata value to output bands` is empty (`not set`). See screenshot:
   [image]
2. Output is a black/white raster as seen on the next screenshot: white for your polygons with vaule=200 und black (=0) for everything outside in the extent of the raster layer.

   Run `Menu Raster / Raster calculator` and add the two layers by double_clicking on the two available rasterbands above and add them. The output of this is what you're looking for:
   [image]

And this is how the output looks like:

[image]